# iron-router data context passing to template

Tags: templates, meteor, iron-router

Using:

Meteor 1.1.0.2

iron:router 1.0.9

I'm trying to pass data from the router to the template. All documentation seems to point to passing as second param of the render function. For the life of me I can't get that to work. It does work if it's the second param of the layout function.

Upon reading, it seems the preferred way is to pass data via the router rather than make a helper. Also, I have globally configured a template to use, so the layout() won't be declared if I'm using the layout in the Router.config.

Please correct any misconceptions.

So, here's my template HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
  <P>pageTitle: {{pagetitle}}</P>
</div>
```

Now I just want something static rather than a result set from a find() on the database.

Here's a snippet in my router.js. This does not work as thought:

```
Router.route('/tour', function(){
  console.log("This is a tour page"); // this works
  this.layout('Marketing'); // different than what config calls
  this.render('tour', {
    data: function(){
      return {pagetitle:'Tour12'}; // template does not see this
   }
  });
  },{
    name: 'marketing.tour'
});
```

If I rewrite this as the folowing, it the variable does get populated as expected:

```
Router.route('/tour', function(){
  console.log("This is a tour page");
  this.layout('Marketing', {
    data: function(){
      return {pagetitle:'Tour12'};
    }
 });
 this.render('tour');
 },{
  name: 'marketing.tour'
 });
```

I've also tried passing all params as an object to no avail (which seems like a great way to pass attributes):

```
Router.route('/tour',{
  name: 'marketing.tour',
  layout: 'Marketing',
  data: {pagetitle:'Tour12'},
  render: 'tour'
});
```

So, am I making some incorrect assumptions? Should I be following a different/better design pattern? Do I just need to call `this.layout()` everytime I want to pass data context? Seems as if Router.map() has been depreciated (as many examples indicate that is one way to inject data to the template? Further thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: I managed to get the options object way to work. It was failing on `render:'tour'`. It should be `template:'tour'`. I can `data:function()` within the obj and within that, I can stick the `console.log('hello')` and it works. Not sure if that's the best way to go about it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I prefer just passing in an options object rather than using a callback function: http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#route-specific-options The `data` key should have a value that's a function that returns something.